# Replace text with jquery?

Tags: jquery, replace

I need to use jquery to replace this

```
<h3 class="pseudo-breadcrumb-total-results">
    "Se han encontrado " <em>23</em> " productos"
</h3>
```

to

```
<h3 class="pseudo-breadcrumb-total-results">
    "Found " <em>23</em> " products"
</h3>
```

i tried with, but not working:

```
$('.pseudo-breadcrumb-total-results').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('"Se han encontrado "', '"Found "'));
    $(this).text(text.replace('" productos"', '"products "'));

});
```

Comment: Are you sure the `"` are not added by the inspector? (try `$(this).text(text.replace('Se han encontrado ', 'Found '));`)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I'm sure that you spot the problem, I'll try your code

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon it worked, but I the <em> tag get deleted... Not a big problem but is there a way to get it back?

Comment: Other answers have already explained that subject. Use `.html` instead of `.text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.html` rather than `.text`. Otherwise, you'll lose the HTML formatting.

```js
$('.pseudo-breadcrumb-total-results').html(function(i, oldhtml) {
  return oldhtml.replace('"Se han encontrado "', '"Found "').replace('" productos"', '"products "');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="pseudo-breadcrumb-total-results">
    "Se han encontrado " <em>23</em> " productos"
</h3>
```

I've also used the function argument to `.html`, so I don't need to use `.each`.

Answer (score 1):

This works by using .html()'s callback function:

```
$('.pseudo-breadcrumb-total-results').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace('"Se han encontrado "', '"Found "').replace('" productos"', '"products "');
});
```

```js
$('.pseudo-breadcrumb-total-results').html(function() {
  return $(this).html().replace('"Se han encontrado "', '"Found "').replace('" productos"', '"products "');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="pseudo-breadcrumb-total-results">
    "Se han encontrado " <em>23</em> " productos"
</h3>

<h3 class="pseudo-breadcrumb-total-results">
    "Se han encontrado " <em>25</em> " productos"
</h3>
```